# mongoose how to take dates between two

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have project - renting app. I need to decide if car is available in dates between date_finish and date_start (includes that dates). I have model - car and order. Orders have  few fields: `dateStart` and `dateFinish`, `carId`
How to take only these carIds that are available between start_date and stop_date (including these 2 days).

Car:

```
    mark:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    model:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,},
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,},
    pic_1:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    pic_2:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },


},
{ collection: 'cars' }
)
```

Order:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userID: { type: String, required: true },
        carID: { type: String, required: true },
        status: {type:String,required:true},
        dateStart: {type:Date,required:true},
        dateFinish:{type:Date,required:true},
        total: {type:Number,required:true},

    },
    { collection: 'orders' }
)
```

Status:1 for new orders, 2 for orders durating now, 3 for archive/completed orders

mongoose query:
 `var orders_n = await Order.find({"status":{'$lte':"2"},$and[{"dateFinish":{ '$lte': start},"dateStart":{}}]"dateFinish":{ '$lte': start}}).select('carID -_id').exec();`

That query doesn't work. Who can help me?

EDIT: I have to (firstly) take orders which :
-date of start and date of end are greater than passed by user date of end
-date of end is lower than passed by user date of start.
In other words - I need cards available in days between passed dates.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document?

Answer (score 1):

Try pass dates this way: `var orders_n = await Order.find({"status":{'$lte':"2"},$and[{"dateFinish":{ '$gte':  new Date()},"dateStart":{ '$lte':  new Date()}}]}).select('carID -_id').exec();`

Comment: I'm affraid it won't work. Your answer return only cars that dates of order are:
- date of stop are greater than nowaday,
- date of start are lower than nowaday.